# sudo make install - what is being installed?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, make

I have to run this cryptic block of code.

```
git clone https://github.com/OpenICC/xcalib.git
cd xcalib
cmake CMakeLists.txt
sudo make install
```

The procedure I'm following mentions the uninstall process.

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Why do the make `install` and `uninstall` commands lack any file or program name? In my mind they should be done like this.

```
sudo make install program_name
sudo make uninstall program_name
```

the same as

```
sudo apt-get install program_name
```

`sudo make install` begs the question "*install what?*"

Comment: For the commands that are executed, see the `Makefile` in that directory, also see `man make`.

Comment: You can use `make -n ......` to see what will be execured

Comment: @RalfFriedl That's the answer to the question; you might as well write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands that are executed by `make install` (or any invocation of `make`) are defined in the `Makefile` (and files included by the `Makefile`). For simple programs, you can just look for a line `install:` and see the commands in the lines below. But makefiles can also be quite complicated and scattered across various subdirectories. For details, see the manual for `make`, or an introduction to `make`.

As @Romeo Ninov wrote, you can also use the command `make -n install` so see what commands would be executed. Beware that for larger makefiles this output may not be accurate, and if you haven't built the program yet it will likely show you all the commands to build before showing the commands to install.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple make files in the directory when you issue this command `sudo make install`. Not requiring a filename argument seems strange. Maybe I'll issue a pull request if I only knew what that meant.

Comment: The default is called `Makefile`, with capital M. There are not multiple files in one directory named `Makefile`. You can pass an alternate make file with `-f`, again for options see the man page.

Answer (score 1):

If no file arg ist passed to make , make looks for a file named Makefile in current dir. With the switch -f an alternative file can be passed to make. See man make for more information. By the way: make is one of these such good old Unix tools so try to get familiar with it ...